# Int in base 2 to binary string python

Tags: python, casting, binary, int, sage

So I have this operation in python `x = int(v,base=2)` which takes `v`as a Binary String. What would be the inverse operation to that?
For example, given `1101000110111111011001100001` it would return `219936353`, so I want to get this binary string from the `219936353` number.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out the bin() function.

```
bin(yourNumber)[2:]
```

will give you string containing bits for your number.

Comment: thanks! If I operate with this string the `0b` from the start won't interfere with the operation, right?

Comment: What exact operation, do you want to perform ?

Comment: @deuseux12 You can use `print bin(219936353)[2:].zfill(8)` to remove that `0b`.

Comment: okey. That binary string is the conversion from the word "hola" to binary. So I would have to convert the binary string to the word. If it gives any problem I'll use Borja solution to take the `0b` out. Thanks

Comment: @deuseux12, This doesn't work: `int(bin(1), 10)`.  See my answer for the first correct solution: `int('{:b}'.format(1), 10)` => `1`.

Comment: @7stud why would interpreting the binary representation as if it was a decimal representation be a useful thing to do?

Comment: @johnsharpe, Huh?  My answer was the only answer that did what the op asked.  If you don't understand why the op wants to round trip a decimal number to a binary string and back to a decimal number, then why don't you  ask the op?

Comment: @7stud did you read the question? That's not what they want...

Comment: @jonrsharpe, The op said, *I want to get this binary string from the 219936353 number*, where ***this*** refers to `1101000110111111011001100001`.  Okay??!

Answer (score 0):

```
num = 219936353
print("{:b}".format(num))

--output:--
1101000110111111011001100001
```

The other solutions are all wrong:

```
num = 1
string = bin(1)
result = int(string, 10)
print(result)

--output:--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 4, in <module>
    result = int(string, 10)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1'
```

You would have to do this:

```
num = 1
string = bin(1)
result = int(string[2:], 10)
print(result)  #=> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> bin(219936353)
'0b1101000110111111011001100001'
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?